# 3-Sum algorithm analysis

Tags: java, algorithm

I knew of 2 approaches to solve 3-Sum problem.

**Problem Statement:**

Given an array S of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in S such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

**Solution1:** Using 2 pointer approach

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    if (nums == null || nums.length < 3)
        return result;

    Arrays.sort(nums);

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || nums[i] > nums[i - 1]) {
            int j = i + 1;
            int k = nums.length - 1;

            while (j < k) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    l.add(nums[i]);
                    l.add(nums[j]);
                    l.add(nums[k]);
                    result.add(l);

                    j++;
                    k--;

                    //handle duplicate here
                    while (j < k && nums[j] == nums[j - 1])
                        j++;
                    while (j < k && nums[k] == nums[k + 1])
                        k--;

                } else if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] < 0) {
                    j++;
                } else {
                    k--;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

**Solution2:** Using maps

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    List<List<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i : nums) {
        map.put(i, map.get(i) != null ? map.get(i) + 1 : 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length - 1; j++) {
            int findMe = -(nums[i] + nums[j]);
            Integer count = map.get(findMe);
            if (count != null) {
                if ((count == 1 && nums[i] != findMe && nums[j] != findMe) || (count == 2 && (nums[i]!=nums[j] || nums[j]!=findMe)) || count > 2) {
                    int min = Math.min(findMe, Math.min(nums[i], nums[j]));
                    int max = Math.max(findMe, Math.max(nums[i], nums[j]));
                    if (map2.get(min + "" + max) == null) {
                        map2.put(min + "" + max, max);
                        LinkedList<Integer> li = new LinkedList<>();
                        li.add(min);
                        li.add(-(min + max));
                        li.add(max);
                        list.add(li);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Context:**

1)Solution1 -- Time complexity of the solution is -> O(nlogn) + O(n^2)    ~ O(n^2)

2)Solution2 -- Time complexity of the solution is -> O(n) + O(n^2) + O(k)    ~ O(n^2)

**My Question:**
Both are O(n^2) algorithm. However for larger input Solution1 is performing better than 2 but as per the Time complexity analysis Solution2 should perform better. Can some one please help me understand why is this so ?

**Input i am using:**

```
[13,14,1,2,-11,-11,-1,5,-1,-11,-9,-12,5,-3,-7,-4,-12,-9,8,-13,-8,2,-6,8,11,7,7,-6,8,-9,0,6,13,-14,-15,9,12,-9,-9,-4,-4,-3,-9,-14,9,-8,-11,13,-10,13,-15,-11,0,-14,5,-4,0,-3,-3,-7,-4,12,14,-14,5,7,10,-5,13,-14,-2,-6,-9,5,-12,7,4,-8,5,1,-10,-3,5,6,-9,-5,9,6,0,14,-15,11,11,6,4,-6,-10,-1,4,-11,-8,-13,-10,-2,-1,-7,-9,10,-7,3,-4,-2,8,-13]
```

Comment: "as per the Time complexity analysis Solution2 should perform better" ... why do you believe this is so?  I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings about O-notation and time complexity, but I'd like to see your answer to help me understand just where your misunderstanding lies.

Comment: __However for larger input `Solution1` is performing better than 2 but as per the Time complexity analysis `Solution2` should perform better__ ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @ajb: I missed that the performance of the solution would depend on values of O(n)+O(k) &  O(nlog(n)) , which is based on the input. Thanks..I believe i got lost on a different track.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that, Asymptotic analysis does not give exact time or space complexity.

However, you are measuring both solutions in exact time duration.

Come to your question, when input is large, in solution2 O(k) is becoming large that's why time used to compute solution2 is more than solution1.

Comment: @RMittal: Why is "k" becoming large? Is it ~n^2 or higher in average for large n? Is it true only for random data. What's your estimation? What if there is no triplets in data with growing n?